# Script stops checking ports after one port is detected as open

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I know this is probably a really simple fix but I cannot think of what I have done wrong. I am stumped. After the port finds out that one port is open, the code spams "not open" despite some of these ports actually in fact being open.

For example, port 135 and 445 are open on my network. When I input a scan between 135 and 445, the computer does not even scan the ports, it just spams that everything past 135 is not open, including 445.

Already tried:

- Stating result variable in both the if and else statements instead of a separate line of code.
- Changing the `spn = spn + 1` line to "port"

```
while True:
   #Shortens string of code.
   sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
   #The IP address that will be implemented into the result.
   ip = str(input("\nCheck IP Address: ")).strip()
   #The port number that will be implemented into the result.
   port = int(input("\nCheck Port: "))
   #What the script is going to check.
   result = sock.connect_ex((ip, port))


   #If user types 0, a complete scan will occur.
   if port == 0:

   #Highest/lowest port to check.
      spn = int(input("\nStarting port: "))
      fpn = int(input("\nFinal port: "))
      print(" ")
      result = sock.connect_ex((ip, spn))
      while spn <= fpn:

   #Prints which ports are open.
         if result == 0:
            print (("Port ") + str(spn) + (" is OPEN"))         

   #Prints which ports are not open.
         else:
            print (("Port ") + str(spn) + (" is NOT OPEN"))

         result = sock.connect_ex((ip, spn))
         spn = spn + 1


   else:
   #Prints if ONE port is open.
      if result == 0:
         print (("\nPort ") + str(port) + (" is OPEN"))

   #Prints if ONE port is not open.
      else:
         print (("\nPort ") + str(port) + (" is NOT OPEN"))
```

The code should be able to check every port individually instead of saying everything after the first port is open.

Answer (score 1):

You can't reuse your `sock` object like that. After the first successful connect, the socket is connected and can't just connect again. This is why all further connects fail.
I would recommend replacing `result = sock.connect_ex((ip, spn))` with this:

```py
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sock:
    result = sock.connect_ex((ip, spn))
    if result: sock.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
```

Comment: Shutdown is not sufficient. You have to close it.

Comment: If the `with` closes the socket you don't need the shutdown at all.